# Finding the set of points of a polar coordinate

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

$\left\{ (r,\theta) : 2\le r\le 6,\frac{\pi}{3}\le\theta\le\frac{5\pi}{6}\right\}$, where $S$ stands for the set of points.

What is the area of $S$?

This is a bit confusing to me. How do I start this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Start with

$$\int_{\pi/3}^{5\pi/6}\int_2^6 r\,dr\,d\theta.$$

Comment: I have not learned integrals yet. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Ah, OK. To help get better answers you should say something about your background in the future.  I'll give a more elementary way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, $\frac{5\pi}6-\frac\pi3=\frac\pi2$ and $\frac\pi2$ is $\frac14$ of $2\pi$. So the area of the sector of the circle with radius 6 is $\frac14\cdot\pi\cdot6^2$. You can find the area of the sector of the circle with radius 2 in a similar manner, then just subtract the areas.

Comment: Is it....$18\pi$?

Comment: Check your calculations again. I'm getting $8\pi$.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. $\frac{1}{4} * \pi * 2^2$. Subtract the two, resulting in $8\pi$.

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: @TunRaczkowski: Thanks for the help!